# On Mersenne composite numbers (need of a proof).

Tags: elementary-number-theory

On the Wikipedia page on Mersenne primes it says

> If $n$ is a composite number then so is $2^n − 1$. ($2^{ab} − 1$ is divisible by both $2^a − 1$ and $2^b − 1$.)

The part inside the brackets isn't clear to me, could someone show the proof for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : $$2^{ab}=(2^a)^b=(2^b)^a$$ and $$x-1|x^n-1$$ for $n\ge 1$